# logic error with unique ID

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that generates unique ID's. It is supposed to increment the ID by a value of 1 each time a user request a new ID. When the table is empty upon request the ID generated will be GPSC0000001. After insertion the next ID should be GPSC0000002 and so on. The first ID generated works fine, l get the ID GPSC0000001, but the second request gives me an ID GPSC610000000 instead of GPSC0000002.

```
   private void btnid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string GetCode = "0";
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from jimmy order by Id desc",cn);
        try
        {
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (dr.Read())
                GetCode = dr["Id"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        if (string.Equals(GetCode, "0"))
            lblID.Text = "GPSC0000001";
        else
        {
            int TotalCodeWithoutLable = GetCode.Length - 6;
            int OldNum = GetCode.Length - TotalCodeWithoutLable;
            lblID.Text = "GPSC" + OldNum + 1 +  "0000000";
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: A part from your error, did you think at what happens if two user calls this code at the same time?

Comment: @Steve thanks for your input, l'm new to programming in general. This is my first shot at a desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is application is used by more than one user simultaneously it could generate duplicate Ids.
I would therefore suggest creating the value within the database using an identity column and computed column to avoid this prospect.

Here is a SQL snippet that will create this for you.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jimmy](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ComputedId]  AS ('GPSC'+replace(str([Id],(7)),space((1)),'0')),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_jimmy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**EDIT**
You don't really need the computed column, you can just add the prefix to the Id column in code if you prefer.

To get the value from the db you can create an insert statement in a stored procedure that returns the computed value.

```
create procedure sp_jimmy as
begin
insert into jimmy default values
select 'GPSC'+replace(str(@@IDENTITY,(7)),space((1)),'0')
end
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the calculation of OldNum is wrong:

```
int OldNum = GetCode.Length - TotalCodeWithoutLable;
```

The above means that you take the length of "GPSC0000001", which is 11 and reduce it by 5 (12-6), which was calculated in the previous row. Then you concatenate the strings "GPSC", "6", "1" and "0000000".

Instead of this, you should get the numeric value from GPSC0000001, and handle it as a number when adding 1 to it. Something like this:

```
int oldNum = Int32.Parse( GetCode.Substring( 4, 7 ) ) + 1;
lblID.Text = "GPSC" + oldNum;
```

Comment: how will l go about this? I tried placing  int i = Convert.ToInt32(GetCode); just before int OldNum = GetCode.Length - TotalCodeWithoutLable; but that didn't work

Comment: What is the value of i after executing that statement?

Comment: i got an error after that : "Input string was not in a correct format". on the line  int i = Convert.ToInt32(GetCode);

Comment: Can you try the exact line I wrote? Substring is important chop off the non-numeric characters.